# Notify Parent window after login complete in child window in Browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook, oauth, socket.io

I am developing a website which have a options of connecting multiple social accounts like connect with facebook etc.
 clicking the connect button opens the facebook ( or any social website) login in popup window.
I want my parent window to get notified when login completes.

I am using node.js on server and using facebook oauth.

One Option i had is to create a socket connection to server in parent window .. give it a unique id and store id in local storage. In child window after logging in successfully and redirected by my server .. i land/redirected to child window with no parameters.. fetch the local storage unique id and sent it to server and server in turn emits event to parent window socket connection with required data/notification.

But i feel using local storage is not a good way. so i am trying to find other ways to achieve this thing and i am stucked on it.

can you guys share your thoughts on the same on how it should be achieved and is there any better way to achieve the goal.

Comment: Two suggestions: read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask AND use a tested and well used OAuth library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not provided any code. So it is quite difficult to assume your current setup.
I am assuming you are opening the popup with `window.open()` method.

You can do something like this on button for social login click:

```
window.loginCallback = function(obj) {
    // do something
};
window.open('url/to/social/login');
```

Then in your popup, after redirection from successful login, redirect to some other page in popup which will have script like this:

```
window.opener.loginCallback(dataToSend);
window.close();
```

If you are with nodejs and expressjs, you can set the `dataToSend` via any templating system.

Hope it helps.

Note: code is not tested, may contain errors.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/opener

Comment: Thanks for the answer... Exactly what i needed... Never Knew that method window.opener exists.